# How constructor can call, own prototype

Tags: javascript

I want to call Constructor A prototype in my code:

```
var A = function () {
 // ? call to A.prototype.a  
};

A.prototype.a = function () {
 // print
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var A = function () {
 // ? call to A.prototype.a
 this.a();
};
```

Comment: but in this case if i print some thing on my prototype it shows the function declaration.

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe you can edit your question to elaborate on what the problem is.